# How to send image data to a custom class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to create a custom class that will create a tile (a small rounded square) when requested, with a small image on it. I can successfully create the tile, as shown in the code below, but I don't know how to pass the class the pictures data.

Is it possible to do this using bitmapData, or by referancing it throught the library (if i store my picture in a movieclip in the library?

Here is my class so far:

```
package  com{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;

public class tileCreator extends MovieClip{

    public var tiled:MovieClip;
    public var sourceImage:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

    public function tileCreator() {
        trace("tile creator");
        tiled = new MovieClip;
        tiled.graphics.beginFill(0x666666, 0.3);
        tiled.graphics.drawRoundRect(-55/2, -55/2, 55, 55, 15, 15);
        this.addChild(tiled);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's possible using BitmapData.

import an image to the library and right-click it to change "settings ...".
you have to check "export for actionscript" and put a name into the second textfield underneath the checkbox - let's say 'MyImage'. (flash automatically adds the base-class of type flash.display.BitmapData).

then you can create an instance of the image saying:

```
var myImage:MyImage = new MyImage();
```

it's a BitmapData object, because your MyImage class extends BitmapData.

then you just have to add the BitmapData to the constructor as an argument (rename your class to Tile, because it's not a creator but the tile itself you create. and use a capital letter!).

```
public class Tile extends MovieClip
{
   public function Tile (img:BitmapData)
   {
      var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(img);
      addChild(bmp);
      tiled = new MovieClip;
      tiled.graphics.beginFill(0x666666, 0.3);
      tiled.graphics.drawRoundRect(-55/2, -55/2, 55, 55, 15, 15);
      addChild(tiled);
      bmp.mask = tiled;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it in the folowin way:

```
function createBitmap ( yourMovieClipYouWantToBeAsImage : DisplayObject ) : Bitmap
{
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( width, height );
        bitmapData.draw ( yourMovieClipYouWantToBeAsImage );
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap ( bitmapData );

    return bitmap; // do what ever you want with it but now as an image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "snapshot" of this using bitmapData. You can then pass this to any other class you want. Code is shown below.

```
//This code goes into your TileCreator-class
public function draw():BitmapData
{
    //True and 0 at the end of creating this bitmap ensure transparancy 
    //for the transparant pixels (else these would be opaque)
    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0);
    bmp.draw(this);

    return bmp;
}
```